# How can I change the parents css property based on the childs class?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of rows of two types. Each row consists of a number of fields. So basically each row has the following structure:

```
<div class="views-row">
  <div class="field1"></div>
  .....
  <div class="fieldN">
    <span>
      <div class="blue"> </div>
    </span>
  </div>      
</div>
```

The question for me is that I need to apply CSS property for the parent div with `class="views-row"` based on the class of the div, which is inside of the div `class="fieldN"`. It may be either "blue" or "yellow".

So based on the class of a div tag which is stored inside of the span, I need to apply a `border-left` property for outer div `class="views-row`"

Could you please help me how can I implement this?

Comment: span is an inline element, so having a div inside span is a bad idea, also, it would be better, if you nest span inside span and give inner span display:block property!

Comment: What have you tried and what are the style to apply ? theres tricks via a pseudo and position to fake background or borders, but there's no parent selector if you want to do more styling.

Comment: It can be done from the child using a pseudo and setting position relative/absolute to both parent and child., you do not need in this a parent selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single border, there is no need of a parent selector  you may fake it via position and a pseudo

```css
.views-row {
border-left:solid red;
position:relative;
}
.views-row .blue:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-3px; /* border width of parent if any */
bottom:0;
border-left:solid blue;
}
.views-row .yellow:before {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-3px; /* border width of parent if any */
bottom:0;
border-left:solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-row">
  <div class="field1"></div>
  .....
  <div class="fieldN">
    <span>
      <span class="blue">i have a blue class, my parent should show a blue left border </span>
    </span>
  </div>      
</div>
<hr>
<div class="views-row">
  <div class="field1"></div>
  .....
  <div class="fieldN">
    <span>
      <span class="yellow"> i have a yellow class, my parent should show a yellow left border</span>
    </span>
  </div>      
</div>
<hr>
<div class="views-row">
  <div class="field1"></div>
  .....
  <div class="fieldN">
    <span>
      <span class=""> My class does not matter here, original red left border of parent remains seen</span>
    </span>
  </div>      
</div>
```

**NOTICE:** HTML structure is now valid, a span can only wrap phrasing content, no block content. the inside div was turned into a span to validate.

Comment: It doesnt affect the outer div unfortunately

Comment: @badm ?? what do you mean, you wanted a different border  on views-row according to the class of the span child . this what it does , blue  gives a left blue border and yellow gives a yellow left border .... If that is not what you want then clarify . and yes it does not affect the outer div because parent selector does not exist as stated many times before and this is a CSS work around, this is no magic nor javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, as far as I'm aware, styling a parent element based on the child element is not an available feature of CSS. You'll likely need scripting for this.

It'd be wonderful if you could do something like div[div.a] or div:containing[div.a] as you said, but this isn't possible.

You may want to consider looking at [JQuery](http://jquery.com/). Its selectors work very well with 'containing' types. You can select the div, based on its child contents and then apply a CSS class to the parent all in one line.

If you use jQuery, something along the lines of this would may work (untested but the theory is there):

```
$('div:has(div.a)').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

or,

```
$('div:has(div.a)').addClass('redBorder');
```

combined with a CSS class:

```
.redBorder
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here's the documentation for the [JQuery "has" selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).